# Find and replace string and print file directory on change

Tags: shell, sed, replace, terminal, find

I am using `find` and `sed` to replace a string in multiple files. Here is my script:

`find ./ -type f -name "*.html" -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i '' "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" {} \; -print`

The `-print` always prints the file no matter if something was changed or not. What I would like to see what files are changed. Ideally I would like the output to be something like this(as the files are changing):

```
/path/to/file was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 9 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 12 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 26 was changed
/path/to/file2 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 1 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 6 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 36 was changed
```

Is there anyway of doing something like this?

Comment: I have run into this before and have never chased a more elegant solution down. However, a quick fix is simply to `grep` whether the file contains  `${REPLACE_STRING}` before calling `sed -i`. Why? `sed -i` will update the file modification time regardless whether a replacement was performed. I would simply do `grep -q "${REPLACE_STRING}" "example.html" && sed -i "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" {} \; -print`. Not elegant, but for a single file, `sed -i` only executes if `"example.html` contains `${REPLACE_STRING}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think you can use `&&` within an `-exec` clause, you'd have  wrap the whole command into `sh -c` or similar.

Comment: Oh, correct, but since the example was for `-name "example.html" -maxdepth 1` a simple `grep` without `find` is all that is needed. Otherwise, a simple helper-script called via `-exec` instead of putting it all after `-exec` will do.

Comment: I'm using this function for multiple files, one include "*.php" so grep wouldn't work :/, I'm going to update my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea. I think `-print` is a deadend for the reason you mention, so it needs to be done in the `exec`. I think `sed` is also a deadend due to the challenge of printing to `STDOUT` as well as modifying the file. So a natural extension is to wrap some Perl around it.

What if this was your `exec` statement:

```
perl -p -i -e '$i=1 if not defined($i); print STDOUT "$ARGV, line $i: $_" if s/REPLACE_STRING/STRING/; $i++' {} \;
```

- `-p` wraps the Perl statements in a standard `while(<>)` loop so the file is processed line by line just like sed.
- `-i` does in-place replacement, just like sed.
- `-e` means execute the following Perl statements.
- `if not defined` is a sneaky way of initialising a line count variable, even though it's executed for every line.
- `STDOUT` tells `print` to output to the console instead of the file.
- `$ARGV` is the current filename, when reading from `<>`.
- `$_` is the line being processed.
- `if` means the `print` only gets executed if a match is found.

For an input file `text.txt` containing:

```
line 1
token 2
line 3
token 4
line 5
```

The statement `perl -p -i -e '$i=1 if not defined($i); print STDOUT "$ARGV, line $i: $_" if s/token/sub/; $i++' text.txt` gives me:

```
text.txt, line 2: sub 2
text.txt, line 4: sub 4
```

Leaving `text.txt` containing:

```
line 1
sub 2
line 3
sub 4
line 5
```

So you don't get your introductory "file was changed" line, but for a one-liner I think it's a pretty good compromise.

Operating on a couple of files it looks like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -maxdepth 1 -exec perl -p -i -e '$i=1 if not defined($i); print STDOUT "$ARGV, line $i: $_" if s/token/sub/; $i++' {} \;
.//text1.txt, line 2: sub 2
.//text1.txt, line 4: sub 4
.//text2.txt, line 1: sub 1
.//text2.txt, line 3: sub 3
.//text2.txt, line 5: sub 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain `-exec` actions and take advantage of the exit status. For example:

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type f \
    -name '*.html' \
    -exec grep -Hn "$REPLACE_STRING" {} \; \
    -exec sed -i '' "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" {} \;
```

This prints, for each matching file, the path, the line number and the line:

```
./file1.html:9:contents of line 9
./file1.html:12:contents of line 12
./file1.html:26:contents of line 26
./file2.html:1:contents of line 1
./file2.html:6:contents of line 6
./file2.html:36:contents of line 36
```

For files without a match, nothing else happens; for files with a match, the sed command will be called.

If you wanted output closer to what you have in your question, you could add a few actions:

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type f \
    -name '*.html' \
    -exec grep -q "$REPLACE_STRING" {} \; \
    -printf '%p was changed\n' \
    -exec grep -n "$REPLACE_STRING" {} \; \
    -exec sed -i '' "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" {} \; \
    | sed -E "s/^([[:digit:]]+):.*/  - $REPLACE_STRING line \1 was changed/"
```

This now first checks if the file contains the string, silently, with `grep -q`, then prints the filename (`-printf`), then all the matching lines with line numbers (`grep -n`), then does the substitution with sed and finally modifies the output slightly with sed.

Since you're using `sed -i ''`, I assume you're on macOS; I'm not sure if the stock `find` on there supports the `printf` option.

By now, we're pretty close to running a complex-ish script on each file that matches, so we might as well do that directly:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in ./*.html; do
    if grep -q "$REPLACE_STRING" "$f"; then
        printf '%s\n' "$f was changed"
        grep -n "$REPLACE_STRING" "$f" \
            | sed -E "s/^([[:digit:]]+):.*/  - $REPLACE_STRING line \1 was changed/"
        sed -i '' "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I like it, but as with my sort of "round-about" `sed` + helper, Ed's `gawk` solution sure does look inviting `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your find+sed command:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.html" -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i '' "s/${REPLACE_STRING}/${STRING}/g" {} \; -print
```

with this GNU awk command (needs gawk for inplace editing):

```
gawk -i inplace -v old="$REPLACE_STRING" -v new="$STRING" '
    FNR==1 { hdr=FILENAME " was changed\n" }
    gsub(old,new) { printf "%s  - %s line %d was changed\n", hdr, old, FNR | "cat>&2"; hdr="" }
1' *.html
```

You could also make it much more robust with awk than with sed if necessary since awk can support literal strings while sed can't

Answer (score 0):

Alright, always defer to Ed's `awk` script for efficiency, but continuing with the `sed` + `helper` script using a preliminary call to `grep` to determine whether your file contains the word to replace, you could use a short helper script taking your `${REPLACE_STRING}`, `${STRING}` and `filename` as the first three positional parameters as follows:

*Helper Script* named `helper.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

test -z "$1" && exit
test -z "$2" && exit
test -z "$3" && exit

findw="$1"
replw="$2"
fname="$3"

grep -q "$findw" "$fname" || exit

echo "$(readlink -f $fname) was changed"
grep -n "$findw" "$fname" | {
while read line; do
    printf -- "  - REPLACE STRING line %d was changed\n" "${line%:*}"
done }

sed -i "s/$findw/$replw/g" "$fname"
```

Then your call to `find` could be, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -name "f*" -exec ./helper.sh "dog" "cat" '{}' \;
```

**Example Use/Output**

Starting with a couple of files named `f` containing:

```
$ cat f
my
dog
dog
has
fleas
```

In a file structure containing the script in the present directory with a subdirectory `d1` and multiple copies of `f`, e.g.

```
$ tree .
.
├── d1
│   └── f
├── f
└── helper.sh
```

Running the script results in the following:

```
$ find . -type f -name "f*" -exec ./helper.sh "dog" "cat" '{}' \;
/tmp/tmp-david/f was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 2 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 3 was changed
/tmp/tmp-david/d1/f was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 2 was changed
  - REPLACE STRING line 3 was changed
```

and the contents of `f` are changed accordingly

```
$ cat f
my
cat
cat
has
fleas
```

If there is no search term found in any of the files located by `find`, the modification times on those files are left unchanged.

Now with all that in mind, if you have `gawk` available, follow Ed's advise, but -- you can do it with `sed` and a helper `:)`

Answer (score 0):

install `Perl` easily for free, define your own strings on bash shell and test here:

```
STRING=
REPLACE=

perl -ne 'foreach(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.html"`){ open IH,$_ or die "Error $!"; print "Processing: $_";while (<IH>) {$s=$_;$t=s/$REPLACE/$STRING/; print "$s --> $_" if $t };print "Nothing replaced" if !$t}'
```

to truly edit it add -i option so it'd be `perl -i -ne`....